# How to get the video resolution in a RTMFP stream?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, rtmfp

I would like to get the NetStream width/height when receiving a RTMFP stream. This is important because the video component needs different measures when, for example, the user receives a 4:3 or a 16:9 stream.

Unfortunately, the onMetaData callback for NetStream does not work as it does for RTMP streams.

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You might try using different ports and see if the onMetaData gives you anything different. I believe the 3 main ones are: 1935, 443 and 80.

The following link can give you further documentation on configuring your server:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashmediaserver/configadmin/WSdb9a8c2ed4c02d261d76cb3412a40a490be-8000.html

Comment: I am using the Adobe Cirrus service to establish a RTMFP connection. There is no need for another server. As it is a UDP connection, the port range varies anyway (also described at your link).